# Pie chart with 3 buckets shows smallest one as 'other'

Tags: dashboard, charts

I have a pie chart with three wedges. Unfortunately smallest wedge comes up as Other.

Any ideas how to solve this?

**Edit**: in case you are wondering this is on a dashboard.

Comment: Adding the code you created to your question would be really helpful.

Comment: No code, this is standard dashboard functionality. Apologies for not including this in original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit your chart and select the **Formatting** tab you should have a checkbox called **Combine Small Groups into "Others"**, un-check this.

[image: Chart Options]

Comment: Brain is an amazing thing. I could swear I knew about this option and I did look just 30 minutes ago in there and it was not there. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

Edit the dashboard, click the wrench beside the pie chart to edit its properties and uncheck the "combine small groups into others" option.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it was always there! Ha! I am disappointed in myself :D